# Android Post to Facebook image timeout

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have simple post-image to Facebook implementation:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", message);
params.putByteArray("picture", data);

String uploadResponse = mFacebook.request("me/photos", params, "POST");
```

This is executed in a Thread.

Now. Is there a way to "timeout" the Facebook request since when the network is slow it lasts forever?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you can timeout the request in the current code.

The [Facebook object](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/android/Facebook.java) calls the *openUrl* method of the [Util](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/android/Util.java) class.
This method uses the [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) class to make the request, and it has the [setConnectTimeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout%28int%29) method which you can use to timeout the request, but the facebook implementation does not let you pass a parameter for it, maybe since this method is new from java version 1.5 and they wanted the SDK to work for lower versions.

If you run your application on 1.5 or higher then you can simply modify the code you have for the facebook SDK to include timeout.