# Android How to set timeout when authorize Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, timeout, authorize

I have some code to connect facebook:

```
facebook.authorize(((Activity) ctx).getParent(), new String[] {},
                requestCode, new DialogListener() {}
```

Usually it works fine. But sometimes I connect to some network don't allow connection to facebook. Then the authorize method will throw

```
 com.facebook.android.DialogError: The connection to the server was unsuccessful
```

On my phone, it took about 20 seconds to throw that exception. But on some other device, it took very long time (maybe because the different setting on different device, I'm not sure). Is there a way to set timeout when the network don't allow connection to facebook.

Comment: Looks like your answer is **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449396/android-post-to-facebook-image-timeout)**. You could try running a concurrent thread (look up Android's `Handler` class and its `postDelayed` method, perhaps), and when it expires, terminate the connection attempt.

Comment: @Soxxeh: Unfortunately that's not the answer for my problem. When I debug, it seems like facebook.authorize never called openUrl method from Util class. So I don't know where to set timeout. And I want to wait until the authorize process finish to continue other work, so I will not running a concurrent thread.